# Verify is that $\overline{R(V + W)}= N(U)^{\perp}$, and that $V = W = 0$ on $N(U)$

Tags: functional-analysis, adjoint-operators

Let $H$ Hilbert space, $U ∈ \mathcal{L}(H )$ be such that $U^* = U$ and $(Ux,x) \geq 0$, in this case, exists $V ∈  \mathcal{L}(H )$ such that $V^*  = V$, $(Vx,x) \geq 0$, and $V^2 = U$, $V$ is called square root of $U$. I am trying to determine a uniqueness of this root. For this if $W$ is any operator
such that $W^* = W$, $(Wx,x) \geq 0$, and $W^2 = U$, I managed to prove that $V$ commutes with $W$,
then we see that $(V − W) \circ (V + W) = 0$ and we deduce that $V = W$ on $R(V + W)$. Therefore $V = W$ on $\overline{R(V + W)}$. what I'm not able to verify is that $\overline{R(V + W)}= N(U)^{\perp}$, and that $V = W = 0$ on $N(U)$. I'm not figuring out how to relate these terms from their definitions, any tips on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $y\in N(U)$ such that $Uy=0$, then $(Uy,y)=(V^2y,y)=(Vy,Vy)=0$, and the same holds for $W$. This shows that $V=W=0$ on $N(U)$. On the other hand, it is quite obvious that $U=0$ on $N(V)$ and $N(W)$, proving that $N(U)=N(V)=N(W)$.

For the second part, we use that $\overline{R(V+W)}=N(V+W)^\perp $. Knowing that $V$ and $W$ are positive and self-adjoint we have $(Vx,x)=0$ iff $x\in N(V)=N(U)$ and the same for $W$, which can be seen for example by the existence of a positive self-adjoint square root of $V$ (not necessarily unique). It follows then from positivity of $V$ and $W$ that $Vz\neq -Wz$ for any $z\notin N(U)$ such that $N(V+W) =N(V)=N(W)=N(U)$. Hence, $\overline{R(V+W)}=N(V+W)^\perp=N(U)^\perp$.

Comment: Reading calmly what may not be clear is the ending, because $ x \in \overline {R (U)} $ implies that $ x \in \overline {R (V + W)} $? This doesn't seem to be straightforward

Comment: Well, $\overline{R(V+W)}=N(V+W)^\perp$. We have already shown that $V=W=0$ on $N(U)$, on the other hand, if $Vz=0$ or $Wz=0$ then $Uz=0$ showing that  $N(V)=N(W)=N(U)$. Since we can never have $Vz=-Wz\neq 0$ (that would mean $(Vz,z)<0 $ or $(Wz,z)<0$, by the existence of square roots of $V$ and $W$), we conclude that $N(V+W)=N(V)=N(W)=N(U)$. Thus $\overline{R(V+W)}=\overline{R(V)}=\overline{R(W)}=\overline{R(U)}$. Does this help?

Comment: @RicardoFreire, I editted the original answer, so that this point should be more clear.

Comment: Yes, it helps a lot! Thank you